# Long thread with multiple insert without lock

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

We have a very long process that make some calculation and insert some data in a table (around 40 000 rows) .
It can take up to 15min.
If it failed, all data inserted must be removed.

If we use transaction, it will lock table for all user that must be able to insert, update (separate data) or read.
But if we don't, inserted data before failure will remain there.

What is a the best way to do so?

Comment: you can use a table as temp , insert all data then copy data as batch with storeProcedure

Comment: Seems like you need some type of shadow or temp table. You can then copy data from the shadow table to the real table on completion.

Comment: Another option is to wrap everything in a SqlTransaction. If it is just inserts you could use `IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted`, I believe that should not force a table lock so other operations should not be effected. If for some reason it does you could enable Snapshot isolation on the DB and use `IsolationLevel.Snapshot`. See also [`SqlTransaction.IsolationLevel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.isolationlevel?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlTransaction_IsolationLevel)

Comment: Thanks all. Temp table seems a good idea and I didn't know the IsolationLevel.Snapshot.
I'll try both

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temp table as said above and have the transaction lock that table instead, but that may bring some issues depending on the actual table structure.

Another option is that you keep track of all inserted and updated data, so you could revert it back later on exception, this way you won't have to use a transaction.
But this way is really a pain and way to much code to be implemented to handle this.

Now the last option I have which is the best option there is. Is that to stimulate and validate all the data and then when all things check up you do your database operation lastly where you are 100% sure nothing will go wrong.